# function and module having same name causing problems when using function name as argument

Tags: python, argument-passing

I have a module named fp in which resides a function also called fp. When I try to use the function name as an argument (in another module), I run into TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Is there some way to deal with this other than renaming my function (or module) or doing import as some other name, to avoid the conflict? Its no big deal to do so , just curious

file fp.py

```
def fp(x):
    code
```

file myfile.py:

```
import fp    
def fun(function=fp.fp)
        argument = 3
        return(function(argument))
```

Comment: You can import the module in another name using `import fp as something`. Then use `something` instead of `fp`. Or you can assign `fp.fp` to a variable of a different name and use that.

Comment: yeah i noted that possibility in the question.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the `fp.fp` in parenthesis when passing it in?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this situation. My function passes through fine.

Comment: same thing here ... I've just copy-pasted your code and it runs fine